# How to access the real App in prepare_arguments in Catalyst::Model::Adaptor

Tags: perl, adapter, catalyst

I've got a catalyst specific model class that I'd like to instanciate
by wrapping it with the help of a Catalyst::Model::Adaptor

```
package MyClass;
use Moose;
has 'c' => ( is => 'ro' , isa => 'Catalyst' );
1;

package MyAPP::Model::MyClass
use base 'Catalyst::Model::Adaptor';
sub prepare_arguments {
       my ($self, $app) = @_; # $app sometimes written as $c
       return { c => $app };
}
1;
```

The problem is that here $app is not an instance of MyAPP, but just
the class name 'MyApp' .

How do I access the instance of MyApp from this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. If you need an instance of the app, you need to build the model per request. [Catalyst::Model::Factory::PerRequest](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Model-Adaptor/) will help!